# How to export JTable java swing /jidesoft cell background colors to excel .xls file using hssfTableUtil

Tags: swing, export-to-excel

How to export JTable java swing /jidesoft cell background colors to excel .xls file using hssfTableUtil ?(I do not want to use .csv)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you use Jide's CellStyles for the colors it is done automatically, otherwise you'll have to write your own POICustomizer.

Relevant Jide support forum is: http://www.jidesoft.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=11 (customer only though).